# Egg, sausage, bacon and spam (lovely spam!)

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

You are given four integers: \$e,s,b\in\{0,1\}\$ and \$S\in \{0,1,2,4\}\$, where \$e,s,b,S\$ stand for egg, sausage, bacon and spam respectively.

Your task is to figure out whether the corresponding ingredients match a valid entry in the following menu:

```
 [e]gg | [s]ausage | [b]acon | [S]pam
-------+-----------+---------+--------
   1   |     0     |    1    |   0
   1   |     1     |    1    |   0
   1   |     0     |    0    |   1
   1   |     0     |    1    |   1
   1   |     1     |    1    |   1
   0   |     1     |    1    |   2
   1   |     0     |    1    |   4
   1   |     0     |    0    |   4
   1   |     1     |    0    |   2
```

This is a subset of the menu described in the famous [Monty Python's sketch](https://www.businessinsider.com/email-term-spam-junk-mail-actually-stems-monty-python-sketch-2017-1), where dishes based on other ingredients are omitted.

### Rules

- You can take \$(e,s,b,S)\$ in any order and any convenient format as long as they are clearly separated into 4 distinct values as described above (e.g. claiming that your code takes a single bitmask with all values packed in there is not allowed).

  *Examples:* `[1,0,1,4]`, `"1014"`, or 4 distinct arguments
- Each value is guaranteed to be valid (i.e. you don't have to support \$e=2\$ or \$S=3\$).
- You may return (or print) either:

  - a truthy value for *matching* and a falsy value for *not-matching*
  - a falsy value for *matching* and a truthy value for *not-matching*
  - 2 distinct, consistent values of your choice (please specify them in your answer)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

### Test cases (all of them)

Format: `[e, s, b, S] --> matching`

```
[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] --> false
[ 0, 0, 0, 1 ] --> false
[ 0, 0, 0, 2 ] --> false
[ 0, 0, 0, 4 ] --> false
[ 0, 0, 1, 0 ] --> false
[ 0, 0, 1, 1 ] --> false
[ 0, 0, 1, 2 ] --> false
[ 0, 0, 1, 4 ] --> false
[ 0, 1, 0, 0 ] --> false
[ 0, 1, 0, 1 ] --> false
[ 0, 1, 0, 2 ] --> false
[ 0, 1, 0, 4 ] --> false
[ 0, 1, 1, 0 ] --> false
[ 0, 1, 1, 1 ] --> false
[ 0, 1, 1, 2 ] --> true
[ 0, 1, 1, 4 ] --> false
[ 1, 0, 0, 0 ] --> false
[ 1, 0, 0, 1 ] --> true
[ 1, 0, 0, 2 ] --> false
[ 1, 0, 0, 4 ] --> true
[ 1, 0, 1, 0 ] --> true
[ 1, 0, 1, 1 ] --> true
[ 1, 0, 1, 2 ] --> false
[ 1, 0, 1, 4 ] --> true
[ 1, 1, 0, 0 ] --> false
[ 1, 1, 0, 1 ] --> false
[ 1, 1, 0, 2 ] --> true
[ 1, 1, 0, 4 ] --> false
[ 1, 1, 1, 0 ] --> true
[ 1, 1, 1, 1 ] --> true
[ 1, 1, 1, 2 ] --> false
[ 1, 1, 1, 4 ] --> false
```

*<sub>Spam spam spam spam. Lovely spam! Wonderful spam!</sub>*

Comment: Can we take input as a string like "4101", or does that fail the "clearly separated" rule?

Comment: @Grimmy I assume that it stands for `"Sesb"`, which is fine.

Comment: The new title is much better

Comment: Bloody vikings...

Comment: May we take a decimal representation of the four values (e.g. `[ 0, 1, 1, 2 ]` as `112`)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I'd say no because that's not really 4 distinct values anymore (whereas a string is OK because it's made of 4 distinct characters).

Answer (score 19):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 32 bytes

```python
"001111020114001410120110".count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDNbsMgEITvfopVTqCiikl8quRrXyC9pTk4FUksIccC3KpP767z09Y2i5B2GZbh03Tf6XxpN8Oxeh9W1oKXXXMpuS9hMfZ29fxx6ds0fJ0b7wgvBXlDqQ4nl6gi91l71bRdn5TWBSlnojmYreYrXxBfcBNTUFE/jeVwK@5WtvwiuMgjx9GDT11o2qSuWnX/RA@7HVnz2LQ39Fr76PbFfx2Cvhb0MqdD8IfgD8EfOX8I/BD4IfBD4IfAD4Eff/xvoZ/JM3sI8WMS/68NhPQxSX82/oBfysjLWXNkzCGgZ5PHJPmlTZkbz7Ejzw6BfZH7Dw)

Takes input in `'sbeS'` order as a single string, like `'1102'`. Simply checks whether the string appears as a substring of the hardcoded string, using the object method to avoid needing to write out a costly `lambda` to define a function.

The desired strings are squished together as much as possible via overlapping. For example, the part `"001111020114` checks for `0011`, `0111`, `1111`, `1110`, and `1102`. The fact that `2` and `4` can only appear as the counts of spam, which is listed last, lets us append strings directly to their right without false positives. I played with the order of the inputs to try to overlap more, but there might be a better outcome.

I suspect this approach can be beaten with a modulo chain or similar using number inputs.

Comment: [-1 Byte](https://tio.run/##dZBBTsMwEEX3OcUsbWEh/@AFIGXLBcqudJFGLo1kJZHtQHv64FIKJPFIkSb5Hr88/eEcj333MB2qt6lvotCnUtdaP5Wm1KbRutHmUd43/djF6fPYOkt4LsgpirV/t5Eqsh@1E203jFFIWZCwKqi92sh05ApKB@klRC@CvLuM/XXY69ikG96GtHK4MNLX4Nsuiu@s@vmJnLZb0ur20E7RS@2C3RX/czB5yeQml4Phg@GD4SPHB@MPxh@MPxh/MP5g/PHn/@rHRbzAg6kfs/p/MWDax6z9xfpNfh0jH2fhyMDBqGebx6z5Ncbk1nPuyLuDcV/1/gU)

Comment: How did you compute the overlaps? Did you do this by hand? :o

Comment: @wilkben A nice idea! Post an answer and [collect your bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18334/20260)!

Comment: @RGS Kind of. I wrote code to count and list the overlaps for each permutation. But I was too lazy to code up the graph algorithm to split them into paths, so I did a couple of the promising-looking ones by hand.

Comment: @xnor I added [an answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199770/88089) but I'm unable to edit the post you linked to claim the bounty.

Comment: Correct suspicion about a modulo chain or similar - [I found a 29](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199857/53748).

Comment: I know the post is old, but I just wanted to mention that `b"\0.....\0.....".hex().count` works for 29. I do suspect switching up the order of the variables to eliminate the `\0` and/or brute-forcing for a shorter overlap sequence can bring this down to at least 27.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes

```python
oct(0x20a00924204c00c048).count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBTsMwEEX3OcUsbWEh/@AFIGXLBcqudJFGLo1kJZHtQHv64FIKJPFIkSb5Hr88/eEcj333MB2qt6lvotCnUtdaP5Wm1KbRutHmUd43/djF6fPYOkt4LsgpirV/t5Eqsh@1E203jFFIWZCwKqi92sh05ApKB@klRC@CvLuM/XXY69ikG96GtHK4MNLX4Nsuiu@s@vmJnLZb0ur20E7RS@2C3RX/czB5yeQml4Phg@GD4SPHB@MPxh@MPxh/MP5g/PHn/@rHRbzAg6kfs/p/MWDax6z9xfpNfh0jH2fhyMDBqGebx6z5Ncbk1nPuyLuDcV/1/gU)

Based on [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199678/88089)

Comment: Congrats! I've posted a bounty and will wait the week before awarding it to draw more visibility to your answer. And if you're interested in more, I have [plenty of answers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18334/20260) to be beaten.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>29 28</s>  25 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546)! (Suffixing a string as the `hash` input)

```python
lambda s:hash(s+'?pB{')%3
```

An unnamed function accepting a string of digit characters, `egg+bacon+spam+sausage` (e.g. `'0040'`) which yields a falsey value (`0`) if on the menu or a truthy value (`1` or `2`) if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJNbsMgEIX3OcVsKkChFeOwihRFyhW6zQa3/olUYys4iyrp2V0rBoXXBlug8bwPP5gZvse298VU747Tl@vKT0dh27rQyrAW@@FwFeplMw3nkx9JVBSopHe60f7oX@NYx1Ws6v5MVdNoCoPr5tldgmsqTaX76D2dPEnJmsz9ZaUpRvyIYhqiLJeU89cCOAtKC7ssShM588gZ8GKSFwNRyjFwDBwD989nxhXAoTMLSgtK@1fJcIPZabMzMDhj8MLghZ/cZ8al/6ntiuaxNMNSaChxKry4CU21FNef5RFvc2d0bpR3BqRxA6WmXw)**

This was found by [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546) using [this code](https://gist.github.com/Lydxn/5cc75ab94c18056427823b9d4b67dc02) ([Try it online](http://clang.llvm.org/), limited to printables, which finds the above).

---

**28 byter...**

```python
lambda*i:hash(i)/442%89%22%5
```

An unnamed function accepting four integers, `sausage, bacon, spam, egg` which yields a falsey value (`0`) if on the menu or a truthy value (`1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`) if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLNCsIwEITvPsVeSluNmA0RVBAfwquXVPsHmharB8F3r8UmmFFDaNnOfM0km/Zxqxqr@mJ76M/mkp3MtN5UpquSOl1oraLVOlIqWvbttbY3inPqKKM9PWl3sHM3Zu4dT4rmSnlZCupacxme5t6ZMheUmWNjqbaUJCxIvienglzFn8rJUAWadw5fFXAanBr@Mjql4@RHk5BF@iwSKq8xcAwcA/eTM@AUcJhMg1ODU387GU4w2G2wB4ZkDFkYsvCf8ww4v166mdAwxsswNhpa7BsfP2NBRfJfHLi0fwE)**

---

**Another 28:**

```python
lambda*i:hash(i)/8883%55%8-2
```

[Try it here!](https://tio.run/##bVLLCsIwELz7FXuRtppitkYogvgRXr2k2hdoWmw9CP57LTbBjLqEhM3MJJPdtI@@akwyFLvjcNHX7KwX9bbSXRXW0SpN0/V8s5mncTK0t9r0FOTUUUYHetL@aGIbS7sGs6K5UV6WgrpWX8dZ3ztd5oIyfWoM1YbCkAXJ9@BIkM34k1kYMg9zzHE3AZ0CpoJTJqa0OvnBJHiRzouEzGEMOgYdg@7Hp6dLQIfOFDAVMNU3k6GC3mu9NzA4Y/DC4IX/1NPTufui7YzGmD7D1GhosWt88AwEFaH3FRw80aPhBQ) (accepts `egg, spam, bacon, sausage`)

---

**29 byters...**

```python
lambda*i:hash(i)/676%86%9%6-2
```

[Try it here!](https://tio.run/##dVLLCsIwELz7FXspbTVitoT6APEjvHpJtS/QtFg9CP57rbbBjI8lLGx2Jpl91LdLUZmozda79qhPyUGPy1WhmyIow1k8j71F7C29eBq19bk0F/JTaiihLd1pszPTwSZP54@y6kxpngtqan3qvL42Ok8FJXpfGSoNBQELkq/DoaAh4nc0pCFychbZ3UbAU4BU8EqPlANPvnMStEirRUJkcww8Bh4D70unw4uAh8oUIBUg1SeSoYNOtU4NDMoYtDBo4R/9dHj2v3A1os76TegHDSO2g/fvvqAs@LsKYfsA) (accepts `egg, spam, sausage, bacon`)

Or one which returns `True` if on the menu or `False` otherwise:

```python
lambda*i:hash(i)/64%31%14%8<2
```

[Try it here!](https://tio.run/##bZJNDsIgEIX3nmI2TVvFyFRijNF4CLduqPYvUdpYXZh499q0EHkqIZBh3gcPhuZ5L2uTdPnu2F30NT3rabUpdVtGVbxYqWDJAatgvU265laZO4UZtZTSgV60P5q5bTM7h5O8vlFWFILaRl/7UT9aXWSCUn2qDVWGoogFyaFzLMhG/IlsGiIv55T9agKcAqWCXUaltJz85CR4kc6LhMjlGDgGjoH78elxCXDoTIFSgVJ9Kxle0LutdwcGZwxeGLzwn/f0OHdevJlQ38bPMBYaSuwKH75CQXn09QsGYNDF3Rs) (accepts `spam, sausage, egg, bacon`)

Comment: A nice idea and well-executed. I'm curious how you found these chains. I'll post [your bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18334/20260) after wilkben's, since I can only have one on this question.

Comment: I wonder, since the challenge allows input to be taken as a decimal number like `1102`, whether this could be used for a mod chain on the number directly that saves on writing `hash()`. I expected because theses number are less well-distributed, they'll be harder separate with a mod chain, but it does give 6 more bytes to work with.

Comment: I found chains by reducing the two sets in nested `for` loops `continue`-ing on intersection, only showing progressively shorter or equal length code, along with the sets (I spotted a `{0, 1}` along the way to give the `<2` solution). I'm not sure we can take an integer due to "as long as they are clearly separated into 4 distinct values" and that `0112` is not `112` in Python. If we could then one trick might be something like `lambda n:a**n/b%c%d`.

Comment: ...the exponentiation trick might lead to much shorter solutions with the `hash` too but the numbers are too big to make a naive search possible - maybe there is some maths that could be used to aid us there?

Comment: (EDIT ^) \$a^b\mod c=((a\mod c)^b)\mod c\$ and \$a^{d+e}=a^d\times a^e\$ I guess...

Comment: If you input a string, you can obtain this 27-byte solution `lambda s:hash(s+'gE.P')%3%2`. The order is `egg, bacon, sausage, spam`.

Comment: @dingledooper I think you should post that find yourself! Happy to put it here if you don't want to though.

Comment: I've gotten it down to 25 bytes: `lambda s:hash(s+'?pB{')%3`. It returns a Falsey value if on the menu, as in your 28 (order is `egg, bacon, spam, sausage`). While I don't quite feel like posting, it would be nice to have this method included in your post. And if it interests you, [here's](https://gist.github.com/Lydxn/5cc75ab94c18056427823b9d4b67dc02) the brute force program which found it.

Comment: Great stuff @dingledooper! I've added it to this post.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
•ʒº-ép•bsCè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xDcIwEEV7pohcx1K@45oUROwRSxRUIHkBZmAEKlghZdIxBos490xO8pP97935lqd0vZQ@nMfBNd4fGzeU3@P1fS6zXz93u6Z8Wt@lLZ3VQSCACOyITGQik2XCE57whCc8oRgssu4OnkyACILw/uAPFO2oS2tDeHTZbLUB)

Inputs as a string `"Sesb"`. Outputs 0 for matching and 1 for non-matching.

```
•ʒº-ép•      # compressed integer 269454360636
       b     # convert to binary: 11111010111100101110110100000000111100
        sC   # convert the input from binary: 8S + 4e + 2s + b
             # (this doesn't error out on digits > 1)
          è  # use this value to index in the above bitstring
```

Comment: Really nice solution :D +1

Comment: I don't know 05AB1E at all, but from the description, it sounds like something like 1101 would match even though it's not on the menu. How does the solution prevent that?

Comment: @MichaelMior 1101 *is* on the menu. As explained in my answer, I take input as "Sesb", so 1101 stands for spam, eggs, and bacon, which is the fourth entry in the menu.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake :) Does this mean there aren't any substrings which are *not* on the menu which appear when the menu is given in this order?

Comment: @MichaelMior What do you mean by substrings? My answer doesn't have anything to do with substrings. Are you thinking of [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199678/6484)?

Comment: A port of xnor's answer would be [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY0xCsJAEEX7nCKkNpAXtTUg4j0ULLQRzAWsPYWksLe0jdjmEF5knbcuzMD/@/6fc7/bHw9p3m43XVXW9aqsuvS9Dqf3bXp97tPzMj5CLtf9OKRZauIVMbha16Jo0EMPPcJDDjnkkEMOOUTi0ypMIIIJTCCsB5nzhnBoZS7IMQ/9OZvhBw).

Answer (score 7):

## x86-16 machine code, 30 bytes

```
D0 E3       SHL  BL, 1              ; e << 1 
0A FB       OR   BH, BL             ; BH = e << 1 | s 
D0 E7       SHL  BH, 1              ; es << 1 
0A C7       OR   AL, BH             ; AL = e << 2 | s << 1 | b 
D0 E0 03    SHL  AL, 3              ; AL =<< 3 (80186+ only)
0A C4       OR   AL, AH             ; AL = spam table value 
B1 09       MOV  CL, 9              ; search 9 entries 
BF 013B     MOV  DI, OFFSET SPAM    ; in SPAM table 
F2/ AE      REPNZ SCASB             ; search table - ZF if found, NZ if not 
C3          RET                     ; return to caller
SPAM        DB   28H, 38H, 21H, 29H, 39H, 1AH, 2CH, 24H, 32H    ; SPAM table
```

Input as `BL = e`, `BH = s`, `AL = b`, `AH = S`.  Output `ZF` if valid entry, `NZ` if not valid

Encodes the input values into a 6-bit binary value (`00esbSSS`), and compares against the table of known valid results.

Here's output from a little test program for PC DOS that takes input from command line:

[image]

Note: Due to the use of `SHL AL, imm8`, this won't work on an 8088-based PC/XT. It would be +1 byte to do `MOV CL, 3 / SHL AL, CL`.

Answer (score 6):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>61</del> <del>59</del> <del>56</del> <del>34</del> <del>32</del> <del>30</del> 27 bytes

```php
<?=74958>>33-$argn%95%34&1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwxDsIwEAXRnnMQukgMdgQRIXTcgwpoEgs4P8uOJW/xNXrt2SKm6@VYx@E0z6X02/v7sXTj0JW64xyxz7fJj@fgqXlwww03csMOO@ywww477MgOPfTQQw899NBDDz300EMPPfTQy1N/a/u@1uUT/e0P)

Each input (ordered esbS) is read as a decimal value and the modulus buckets them into a smaller range (i.e. a hashing function), which are then looked up in the "bit table" of the constant.

The hashing function has clashing values, but these all coincide when values are either truthy or falsy.

Answer (score 5):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <strike>24 bytes</strike> 21 bytes

This refinement of the solution is thanks to Grimmy, who took my formatting and used stronger stack manipulation to save a bunch of whitespace and variable assignment.

The following is the code (for the first time, newlines are necessary).

```
'\;*
>>
@^*

;>'n/\=~
```

Grimmy's solution at the bottom takes in a string of a list of arrays and applies the following operation to all of them, even though it's not strictly necessary. Golfscript can take input as a header, which is where my TIO references. Grimmy's is much cleaner to see all the outputs.

Input is a stack-dump of four elements: e, s, b, S

For the following explanation, I'm going to use N as a "newline" indicator so you can understand how this works in my formatting.

```
'\;*N>>N@^*NN;>'n/\=~ #Do as instructed
'              '      #String notation
'\;*N          '      #[Index 0] Pop s, then multiply e and b
'    >>N       '      #[Index 1] A trickier operation, will explain at bottom.
'       @^*N   '      #[Index 2] s*(e xor b)
'           N  '      #[Index 3] Can never be called.
'            ;>'      #[Index 4] Ensure e=1, s=0.
'              'n/    #Split the string on newlines (stack is e s b S "x/y/z")
                  \   #Swap the top two elements of the stack (e s b "x/y/z" S)
                   =  #Find the (top element)th element of (second element)
                    ~ #Then evaluate it.
```

So, why do these operations work?

```
m=0
 [e]gg | [s]ausage | [b]acon | spa[m]
-------+-----------+---------+--------
   1   |     0     |    1    |   0
   1   |     1     |    1    |   0
As long as e=1 and b=1, s can be anything. So if m=0, our output can be e*b

We do this in the program with {\;*} 

This removes s from the array, then multiplies e and b together. If they're both 1, yay! If not, then we get a 0.

m=1

 [e]gg | [s]ausage | [b]acon | spa[m]
-------+-----------+---------+--------
   1   |     0     |    0    |   1
   1   |     0     |    1    |   1
   1   |     1     |    1    |   1

3/4 binary options. As long as we have e=1, and we DON'T have s=1, b=0, then we're good.
e*NOT(s*NOT(b))
or
e*(NOT(s) + b)

So, why does {>>} work?

It starts by checking that s>b. This should NEVER be true. So we have 0.
Then we check if e>0, which is true if e=1 and the above worked. If the above *didn't* work, then e>1 will never be true.


m=2
 [e]gg | [s]ausage | [b]acon | spa[m]
-------+-----------+---------+--------
   0   |     1     |    1    |   2
   1   |     1     |    0    |   2
As long as s=1, then we have an xor situation!
s*(e xor b)


{@^*} pulls the e to the top of the stack, then xors it with b.
Then the * multiplies that result with s.

m=4
 [e]gg | [s]ausage | [b]acon | spa[m]
-------+-----------+---------+--------
   1   |     0     |    0    |   4
   1   |     0     |    1    |   4
As long as e=1 and s=0, we don't care about b.
e*NOT(s)

We just do this with {;>}, which removes b from the equations, and makes sure e>s, which can only be the case is e is 1 and s is 0.
```

There we go! With brainpower combined, feast your eyes upon this beautiful creation!

[Try the 21-byter online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlvqACCBv/VY6y1uOzsuBzitLi4rO3U8/RjbOv@/wcA)
[Try the old 24-byter online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlvqGAAhCb/o6tjrLVqq@3saqsd4rRqDaqt7WpjY2zr/v8HAA)
[Try all examples online on the old solution (26 bytes)! (Courtesy Grimmy)](https://tio.run/##Tc6xCsIwGMTx3acIGTvYnGQrDb5HUxdBEURF3ULy6hFC@FeyHOT43Xd93i@f8/v2@lYbH3ZMe2vmYGyspSwpTkNOIeR0PA3ZpSnkNc6lNfNYF2faW3c9iXQg@Z5ET/RET70nPOEJT3jCE566Iq4St4g1sSE2hNw0ev@eR3Ek8btdsK155M1zJK0/)

Comment: It's funny because I thought about doing it in this way, and I thought about the string-array-splicing thing, but for some reason I never thought about doing both! I'll edit that in :)

Comment: Down to [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##Tc6xCsIwGMTxPU8RuhQ62JxkKw2@h6mLoAgSRd2kefUIJfwjWQ5y/O67Pu6X9/l1e35KGr@7zs7BdrHk3MdpMCGYw2kwZgp9GuOcS1rHcnR2e4upSaQ9ydckeqIneqo94QlPeMITnvBUFXGVuEWsiQ2xIeRNo/fveRRHEr/tgrbmkZvnSFp@).

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlvqACCBv/VY6y1uOzsuBzitLi4rO3U8/RjbOv@/wcA) by using header-input. This is a very clever solution! using line-break comma-notation. I do try to avoid using newlines in Golfscript as a rule since it messes with my explanation block, but I can probably find an equivalent.

Comment: What IO rule allows Golfscript to take hard coded input? I'm pretty sure there isn't one

Comment: @JoKing [There is](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8493/6484).

Comment: @Grimmy I don't think this is a function though? I'm not that familiar with Golfscript, but given that the only thing in the header is the input, and the code doesn't seem to be called from the footer, it looks just like a snippet that relies on the input being on the stack

Comment: The entire program is a single-execution function. It gets called automatically on program compilation and execution. The top comment on that post literally says
"+1, this is the de facto standard for CJam and GolfScript"
All that the "input" tab on TIO does is stick it on the stack anyways, as a string. Golfscript doesn't "take in parameters", so this is how it's done.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>[49](https://tio.run/##dZPRaoNAEEXf/YphX9S4CRljpQ3YnwiUQtIHJUotRmV381DEb7ezNoFEdkBU7uzM3cNl@l/z3bW7qYIMTlOTX4pzDgdZSi2LfVG3QZy@JS/JLt2muzQ8xtHr6hAlqzKKVzoqviZTaqOpVwhxhK28P/AF6/U7VHmjS@@hgFwh5gqJs4CcB3IeyHmg0wM5DuQ4kONAjgM5DuQ48InDqOuTvrRALg5cxnGbhFwauEzjqeEBYqkjo7sN0GWAHII7CVwmsZyUOBucDMgwIMfgyIEWY6P7pjaBOLUi9Lz60nfKwI/uWq/qFNgNgrqdv3rvAf33Erqroa2y2r17HkkDAEoJWkIh4UBH7JxN0@VnHVCjLf@3zm/aS3trQaoirQpumx3eBJVlYmurvapbE1QiGPwPH@rKtmeZgpIIwP/0xxAGGj8C3WFQ43yXgc6Mlmj6Aw)</s> 44 bytes

```
lambda S,e,s,b:269454360636>>8*S+4*e+2*s+b&1
```

You can [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##dZPRaoNAEEXf/YphH6rRTcgYkTaQ/ESgFJo@KFFqMSq7m4cifrudtQlE2QFRmdk7dw@X6X7Nd9vsxhIOcB7r7JpfMjjJQmqZ7@NtiukO35Itpsfja3iKkrCI4lBH@QuOptBGk0wI8Qlb@XjgC9brI5RZrQvvqYFcI@YaibOBnAdyHsh5oNMDOQ7kOJDjQI4DOQ7kOHDGYdRtVl9aIBcHLuO4T0IuDVymMRM8QSzryNTdBugyQA7BnQQuk1hOSpwCJwMyDMgxOHKgxdjorq5MIM6NWHlede1aZeBHt41XtgrsBkHVTF@994D@OwntzdBW2dpDPY2kAQCFBC0hl3CiI3bOpm6ziw5IaNv/0ulNe2lvLaiqqFYG96W2xzpVNSYoRdD77z5UpVUcDgoKujT4H/6wgp4mDkC2vRom@57ODBZi/AM). Outputs 0 for a valid recipe and 1 otherwise.

Hats off to @Arnauld for shaving me 5 bytes :)

Borrows [Grimmy's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199644/75323) approach so be sure to upvote that one as well!

Comment: @Arnauld really nice, this essentially slices the end of the binary repr of this integer and then gets the least significant bit with `&1`. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I've ended with the same answer as you! Mine does the opposite: 1 for valid and 0 otherwise. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>52</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>48</s></sup> 44 bytes

```python
lambda e,s,b,S:206163194016>>8*S+e*4+s*2+b&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFNa4QwEIbv/oqph@JHtvi6Iq0Qj/0D25v1oLuRClZFU2kRf7vdQpdFyUAOyUxmXh6e/kd/dO1xreT72hSf5aUgJUZRilMSBjHiI16iAHGaPnsnX3mRP3qhXz5iHeT8NnypxC5GW9Br0YzXe9tpur4Xq@oG0kJR3VJmZRkF4nYo//@di00DXCPkGpGxAS4DXAa4DBgzwHGA4wDHAY4DHAc4Dtw5/rTs6vsIcDqw0XHfBM4GNjb2AzcIQx1M3RwAUwA4BLMJbEwYNkXGASMDGAZwDAYPeWLRJCvH065F/VC32qnsualH7Wh3ocMhpXlaaB4yZ3qQgSulyhdS3706a3V5st31Fw)

Ouputs Truthy for true and Falsy otherwise.

Comment: Nice golfing going here!!

Comment: @RGS Great minds think alike! :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), <s>[13](https://tio.run/##Vc@xDcJAEAXR3FVQgAMGUQGUcXJIgtwA2YHIaMBIJNAERmRQyV0jSwJYI22ywdfobTd9v4uo@bIuj@t7KOOh7u81n1dNGY81D@V5et0iIqV5O/te1zYJfQt9S33/HdqhHdox7VAP9VAP9VAP9VCPqYd8yId8yId8yId8yId8yId8yId8yId8v6/7AA)</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
“BƑṗ©N’Bị@Ḅ
```

You can [try all the test cases](https://tio.run/##Vc@xCcJQGEXh3ikyQASP2AVEMoC9hJQ2kgXsgggprKxE0AEEBzAIFgbcI1nkaaGGA6/5eVwO32pZFOsQuvKUvvZtfXhe5l15TNv7btbetqGtH8nnLxpOo648J001aKpuc12EkGWjOPq@PB5k6Brrmuj679AO7dCOfod6qId6qId6qId69D3kQz7kQz7kQz7kQz7kQz7kQz7kQz7k@135Gw)!

Thank you, @Nick, for saving me 2 bytes. I'm currently tied with the [shortest 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199644/75323) :)

Comment: [Here’s your 11](https://tio.run/##Vc@xCcJQGEXh3ikyQASP2AVEMoC9hJQ2kgXsgggprKxE0AEEBzAIFgbcI1nkaaGGA6/5eVwO32pZFOsQuvKUvvZtfXhe5l15TNv7btbetqGtH8nnLxpOo648J001aKpuc12EkGWjOPq@PB5k6Brrmuj679AO7dCOfod6qId6qId6qId69D3kQz7kQz7kQz7kQz7kQz7kQz7kQz7k@135Gw). You could also have moved the first link in place of the `¢` and put a `¤` for 12 bytes.

Comment: @NickKennedy thanks for the tip! I see you have encoded a different integer. How did you get it?

Comment: I converted to binary with `B` left rotated the binary digits 1 place with `ṙ1` converted back from binary with `Ḅ` and then converted to a base-250 integer with `ḃØ⁵ịOJ`.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 49 bytes

```c
f(e,s,b,S){return 206163194016>>8*S+e*4+s*2+b&1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZPLSsNAGEb3PsVQqOQKOeMQWgp5iS7VRS@JFHSQtK5Knz0qFK04Px8kizAcJofDt6t3r5v4Mk1D1lfHalut8/PYnz7G6HzT0j6wDA1t1y2KddkXoTwWvtzes7pMh3hyb5tDzHJ3vnsfvz6HbPbYVO76uGdX13Xn5nuXzff5U5xVbsh@z/Pvd5UgESQm6QXpTTIIMqRJhCemJ8IT0xPhiemJ8CTtieiJ2RPRE7MnoidmT0RPzJ6Inpg9ET0xeyJ68tOTJBkE@c8TsU/MfSL2ye0@SZJekN68MwgypO9EeF57pkkEiUl6QRqeCE/SnoiemD0RPY19IvbJ7T7TfxsEGdJ3IjyNnoiemD0RPTF7Inr@3edl@gQ)

Ouputs `1` for true and `O` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>51 41</s> 36 bytes

```ruby
->*x{"J36:;>'-."[""<<x.join.oct%77]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf106rolrJy9jMytpOXVdPKVpJycamQi8rPzNPLz@5RNXcPLb2f7SBjmGsXkFRfkppcokGmKcDJbUM9PRMYjX1chMLqmsqagoUoit00qK1KmKB2gA)

Returns `nil` (falsy) or a string (truthy).

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 17 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
"~ "øUn5 d
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=IoKbfoOcIIaBmCL4VW41IGQ&input=IjExMTIi)

```
"~ "øUn5 d     Program taking U, the string in "esbS" form
"~ "           String with values 130,155,126,131,156,32,134,129,152
              ø          Does it contain
               Un5       The input converted from Base-5 string to a number
                   d     And converted to a char?
```

Comment: Looks like some special characters are missing from your code.

Comment: @Grimmy the unprintable characters don't show up

Comment: Then please give an explanation of your code, since it's illegible otherwise.

Comment: @Mathgeek Just did

Comment: Does Japt's code page really include various unprintable characters or are you using a different one?

Comment: @JoKing Japt uses Latin-1, so 0x00 - 0x1F and 0x7F - 0x9F are all unprintables

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 23 bytes

```
×+/'é¢~â£ ≠ü⌹'=⎕av[5⊥⎕]
```

Index origin = 0

Prompts for a vector 4 integers and returns 1 for true zero for false.

Explanation:

Converts input vector from base 5 to an integer used to index into APL+WIN's atomic character vector (extended ASCII) and checks if it is in the menu which has similarly been converted to characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
•ÿŸ»¢•bŽ9“«S4äøJIå
```

Input as a concatenated string of \$e||s||b||S\$. If this is not allowed, a single byte has to be added for an explicit `J`oin.

Pretty straight-forward approach, so will golf it down from here.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9vc2FiaWX//@KAosO/xbjCu8Ki4oCiYsW9OeKAnMKrUzTDpMO4SknDpf//MTEwMg) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##Jc2hCsJQHEbxVxk3L3hkxWS3GsXgwGAyCMLakg9gNg1NvsBARNhlL7IXuW47t/wvfBx@58uhPB3TtVqHbLjds7BOQ93EX992n64Zv2X/XQ31o3tvi/iM7aaKr5SnXViML@TTwbP0FPPBDTfcmDfssMMOO@yww465Qw899NBDDz300EMPPfTQQw899Ji8/R8).

**Explanation:**

```python
•ÿŸ»¢•              # Push compressed integer 4221990791
      b             # Convert it to binary: 11111011101001100111011110000111
       Ž9“          # Push compressed integer 2442
          «         # Merge them together: 111110111010011001110111100001112442
           S        # Convert it to a list of digits
            4ä      # Split it into 4 equal-sized parts
              ø     # Zip/transpose; swapping rows and columns, to create quartets
               J    # Join those together
                Iå  # And check if the input-string is in this list
                    # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•ÿŸ»¢•` is `4221990791` and `Ž9“` is `2442`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
№%')-/36AE§γ↨θ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5vxRIKqmqa@rqG5s5uirpKDiWeOalpFZopOsoOCUWp2oU6igYaQKB9f//0dEmOgoGYGQYG/tftywHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input ingredients as a list in reverse order and outputs a Charcoal boolean i.e. `-` for matching and nothing for non-matching. Explanation:

```
             θ  Input list
            ↨ ² Convert from "base 2"
          §γ    Index into printable ASCII
№%')-/36AE      Is the result contained in the given literal?
                Implicitly print.
```

One of my rare answers that don't use any characters with unusual widths meaning that the explanation lines up nicely for once.

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 38 bytes

```
?112,1001,Z+3,Z+6,Z+1,Z+3,1102,Z+8,Z+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/397Q0EjH0MDAUCdK2xiIzYAYwjY0NDACMixAAv//A5UBAA)

Builds a list of all of the possible inputs (in integer form) and returns True if they are in the list.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 67 bytes

```
=CHOOSE(D1+1,A1*C1,AND(A1,B1<=C1),AND(B1,A1+C1=1),,AND(A1,NOT(B1)))
```

Follows similar logic to that used by @Mathgeek

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“ṚE⁾’,3ḥỊ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of integers, `[egg, sausage, bacon, spam]`, which yields a truthy value (`1`) if on the menu or a falsey value (`0`) if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO2e5Pmrc96hhpo7xwx1LH@7u@v//f7ShjoIBGJnEAgA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##bZAxCgIxFESvkgOk@BNzBfEQS0qbZS8gWMRtBG@gaGnnARTFRjxI/kXiLrp8BiwSePyZTP60y65b1ar5WG6HuW6emvd@Vq7nct/V9@O11f7SDkfzab2otWngnXg33sm7kUAk37ERjGAkEwVSRnolmk9@SplmQgQiVkYjkA/kA/lgPlAeKI9/BsoD5f3bnbflBrmXQE0IEYgidR2IYkof).

There may well be an 8 or 7 out there using a similar method, it's just a mater of finding them!

#### How?

```
“ṚE⁾’,3ḥỊ - Link: list of integers
“ṚE⁾’     - base 250 number = 11455143
      3   - three
     ,    - pair = [11455143, 3]
       ḥ  - Jelly's hash: use 11455143 as a salt and [1,2,3] as a domain
        Ị - insignificant? (effectively "equals one?")
```

---

**[Another 9](https://tio.run/##bZAxCgIxFESvkgOk@BP@HTzEktJm2QsIFsFG2MZa0Eaw034RK0XvkVwk7qLLZ8AigcefyeRPu@y6Va0lHfLQ59vufX2cStr7kIdzfd2f27K5tOMp6bhe1No08E68m@7o3UQgku/YCEYwkpkCKZVeUfPJTynzTIhAxEo1AvlAPpAP5gPlgfL4Z6A8UN6/3XlbbpB7CdSEEIFIqetApDF@AA)** which takes `[egg, sausage, bacon, spam]` and yields `2` when on-menu or `1` when not:

```
“Ḋẏƭ¢’,2ḥ
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <strike>35</strike> <strike>34</strike> 30 bytes

```javascript
(e,s,b,S)=>s<S?5/S-s&e+b*s:e&b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZPRS4NgFMXf/SvuxhizfbPdWBAzi6AGQW8@RjC16zBMh/dzBeLfbm6u@Nq84Nu55xx/HL6PYBdwVCRbPdvdNLHXTEixCpVve3d8699fX/ozHtM0vOAljcMmJQ1xkKQMHsxdKy6zSCd5BppYt1ZgBaECXwF9bynS9G5DZQFEecYaCuIy1a0zNk5tt9WTGCaDwVEfeN6JvaucTvenh6w8JSfNN5P1qHp1HCcoNuUnZZrfalg9PL88PcJXwDCqusR6fSipgVKmLtAMMQO6Q6u2DkAwV78fqPYnWnt7cCKhLF3J0kKQUO5CuQvlLhS6UOZCmQtlLpS5UOZCmQv/uHRR9ijnVSjPheZc//JQXgvNtXpMR6h@BUVFKsL@IpSRpKXQXKo/byGYBCYUmVBmOt/JfHfD1f5VL4eqe9622/wA)

I wrote a random expression generator and left it running for a few hours to generate the expression following the `=>`. In this answer I am only posting unedited outputs from the generator.

Answer (score 1):

**RUST, 98 Bytes**

```
fn f(e:u8,s:u8,b:u8,x:u8)->bool{match x|s<<3|e<<4|b<<5{17|20|26|42|48|49|52|56|57=>true,_=>false}}
```

[Try it here](https://tio.run/##bVDvS@QwEP3s/hWjH84Waulku@rFtofiDwRBOI77IiJtTbly2VaaFJWmf/uamQVZxJa8mXl5ecnMMBq7GY0CY5@lbHspJ5@1XQQXY/Nblc/z2abpoAmUHE8jQ1ARvHkIj4qq7/W0Lm39D96cybKlU1mWuirLVhOeOJE4cexS4dJTl/50K@FWx251khd2GFX0lBdNqY2aZ7piXbZdEMK02NPKglHWQA78liCMdV//p9B2yvi4Ll8Cp52Ox@518Hn4SdH5PXbQ/riOS/NUvVs6dEYbgX5IHuEIqsPkMAL9gLuF2C2Wu0X6CPs5V6F3mcO47rVWtZUy@6vqLPADgd1FYwmLgi9t@oG6gbaDH9wVvbBt/Eh9FScRbca4DWIbliHkOWfptp@Xoe2s7vaDg5v7PzDJX/MBK7mp2S/lx/hVen1@e3d1Kb@Rz4t5k9C38AsZBWNKiMwj88g8Eo@sR9Yj65H1yHpkPaJAQs8j@yMZEQrOU8r9T8g8Mo/Esz@yv0fBDPkg65H1yHry/wA)